# Derivation of interaction potentials of fundamental forces

Tags: standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, elementary-particles, weak-interaction, strong-force

In *Gauge theory of weak interactions* by Greiner and Müller, they show the following superb comparison of the interaction potentials between particles as a function of separation:

[image: absolute value of potential |V(r)| between elementary particles]

I have never seen this graph anywhere else, and nor have I seen any information on how the lines it plots were or could be derived.  Is there a clear argument to justify these scaling behaviours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a log-log plot the straight lines (Coulomb, gravitation, strong inside $10^{-15}$ m) are the long range power laws ($1/r$) resulting from exchange of massless bosons (photon, gluon, graviton).  I'm not sure what units are being used for the vertical (potential) axis but it is probably eV or MeV (hard to tell on a log-log plot).  For the weak force I'm sure they are just using a Yukawa function ($e^{-mr}/r$) where m is the mass of the weak vector bosons (W,Z).  For the strong force outside the quark confinement radius they are probably using the same with m chosen to be the mass of the pion.

Comment: I like this as an answer, but there are two outstanding questions as far as I can see: (a) the strong force line as plotted isn't actually straight within the atomic radius (any ideas why not?), and (b) it gives no indication on how to derive the relative strengths. Any ideas?

Comment: The strong force inside the nuclear radius is the realm of lattice QCD and this force is complicated by the fact that gluons (unlike photons in QED) couple to each other as well as to quarks.  I'm not an expert here but I know enough to say "its complicated."  The relative strengths are taken from experimental facts (masses, charges, gravitational constant, decay lifetimes, etc).  I'll address these details in an edit if you would like more information.